# How to issue a command to find out the path of python3?

Tags: python

Where do I type the command to get the full path to my Python3? In the terminal or to my Python interpreter? I have tried both and it didn't work in my terminal and there is nowhere to type in Python interpreter. So how do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Please don't include images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command in your terminal should work just fine. I just confirmed this in my linux terminal. Check to make sure you have python3 install and not python2. Also when in doubt try tagging sudo onto the command

Answer (score 0):

Just type in terminal:

```
$ whereis python
```

If not installed - nothing will be shown.